# Veracode directory traversal Issue c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, veracode

I have this code that stores file to server:

```
function void StoreFile(string inputFileName) {
   ...

   var extension = Path.GetExtension(inputFileName);
   if(extension == ".csv") {
       var fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", Session.SessionID, new Guid(), extension);

       var dataFileServerPath = _documentService.getPath(fileName, UserProfile.UserName, UserProfile.SourceID);

       if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataFileServerPath)) {
           try {
              using(FileStream dataFile = new FileStream(dataFileServerPath, FileMode.Create))  { .... }
           }
           cathc(Exception e) { ... }    
       }
    }    
    else {
        throw new NotSupportedFormatError();
    }
}
```

Aftrer Veracode analyze I get Directory Traverse Issue on line `FileStream dataFile = new FileStream(dataFileServerPath, FileMode.Create)`

Why am I getting this issue there, I've checked if file extension is valid for my case and passed that value in fileName. Is this security issues and how to solve this issue?

`_documentService.getPath` just appends path from web.config and filename for specific user, it's not related to user input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the code you've posted here, that looks like a false positive.

Veracode is apparently tracking the `inputFileName` variable (which I assume contains unvalidated user input), and notes that it influences the `extension` variable. Since you later embed `extension` directly into the filename, and read the file that points at, Veracode sees that it is possible that a malicious user would embed a partial path in inputFileName which would then change the directory of the target file...

In this case, Veracode is missing the fact that you already performed input validation (the `extension == ".csv"` check), and absolutely constrained the relevant part of the input to a tight whitelist.

Assuming there is no other relevant bits of code missing from your question, this is safe to mark as false positive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ps. How can I validate user input (for example inputFileName) in other cases and not receive Veracode issues?

Comment: Well, since at the point of insertion you already know that the value you're inserting is ".csv", why not just insert that directly? :-)

Comment: Also, for the general case, this seems like it might be a bug in Veracode, depending on how the rule is defined. Other products allow you to finetune the validation rules, not sure the current solution for Veracode. In general, your approach should be to verify that you've done validation correctly, and not worry about the tool that is there to verify it.

Answer (score 4):

There's no real way for static analyzers to reliably verify that you are in fact *not* using user input. They tend to err on the side of being overly cautious, thereby producing false-positive warnings.